# Changing the date format to mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm

Tags: java, date, formatting

I'm trying to use this code:

```
private static Date getTimeStamp() {
    return new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
}
```

What I'm getting is `2013-03-13 12:46:22.011`

But what I need is that the timestamp should be in the format of `mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm`.

Comment: use SimpleDateFormat for formatting the date. String format = MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm        SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
String    dateString = dateFormatter.format(dateToFormat);

Answer (score 5):

`java.sql.Timestamp` objects (just like `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date`) do not have a format by themselves, so you cannot "have a Timestamp in the format [whatever]".

A format only is applicable when you convert the object to a string for display. You can use `SimpleDateFormat` to convert a `Timestamp` to a string, using the format you want.

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm");
String text = dateFormat.format(timestamp);

System.out.println(text);
```

Comment: :thanx for replying .

I'm not able to relate the things . Sorry for this .
How can i use your code . Though i'm very new to java

Date dateCreated =getTimeStamp();

 private Date getTimeStamp() {
  
  return new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
 }

Comment: I've modified my example to make it a little bit more clear. You'll need to use a `SimpleDateFormat` object to convert the `Timestamp` to a `String`. Then you can display that string, for example with `System.out.println`. Learn more about [working with objects and calling methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/), that will make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps

```
    String date1="2013-03-13 12:46:22.011";
    DateFormat userDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS");  
    DateFormat dateFormatNeeded = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
    Date date = userDateFormat.parse(date1);
    String finaldate = dateFormatNeeded.format(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use SimpleDateFormat http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html to achieve your goal.

For Example:
 new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm").format(timestamp));